# ButtonAction overwrites preceding ButtonActions

Tags: swift, button, alignment, swiftui, tap

I have an Imageview that has six buttons on top of it. Depending on which button is being clicked, I want to change the image. However, somehow the ButtonActions don't work as expected and I wasn't able to figure out how to change the behavior correctly.

The ZStack for the Overlay looks like that:

```
class ImageName: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "muscleGuy"
}

struct MuscleGuy: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageName = ImageName()
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    //the buttons, overlaying the image
                    ButtonActions( imageName: self.imageName).zIndex(10)
                    //the image
                    ImageView(imageName: self.imageName, size: geometry.size).zIndex(2)
                        .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height/2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And to aggregate the different buttons, I created the *ButtonActions*-struct:

```
struct ButtonActions: View {
    @State var imageName: ImageName
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.imageName.name = "arms_chest"
                        print(self.imageName.name)
                    }) {
                        armsRectangle(size: geometry.size)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.imageName.name = "abs_lower_back"
                        print(self.imageName.name)
                    }) {
                        absRectangle(size: geometry.size)
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.imageName.name = "legs"
                    print(self.imageName.name)
                }) {
                    legRectangle(size: geometry.size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The legRectangle contains one rectangle only, whereas the armsRectangle contains three Rectangles and the absRectangle contains two. They are always nested in a HStack.
I don't want to overload my question with code, so here is one example Rectangle:

```
struct absRectangle: View {
    var size: CGSize
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: size.width/8 + 8, height: size.height/9)
                .position(x: -size.width/4, y: size.height/2 - 40)
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: size.width/8 + 8, height: size.height/9)
                .position(x: -10, y: size.height/2 - 40)
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior that occurs is that the legRectangle always takes over the whole screen. So wherever I tab, the legRectangle-action is being executed.
When commenting that section out and assigning the same zIndex to both the armsRectangle and the absRectangle, it recognizes different tap actions. But the behavior isn't correct either. For example only the right ab-rectangle-action is triggered and the left one again also leads to the arms-rectangle-action.

I feel like the behavior has something to do with the alignment within the HStacks/VStacks/ZStack but I can't figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: can you please show us armsrectangle, imageview and legrectangle so we can try to reproduce your problem?